# When an app is launched from the background, will applicationDidBecomeActive get called?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have an app that uses Geofencing. When you cross a geofence, the app is launched - but does it ever go into the 'active' state even though it's launched from the background?  We have pertinent code in applicationDidBecomeActive.  The documentation is unclear.

Comment: Did you test to see what happens? Quicker than posting a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases it should, but it's good to be careful about that. Here's a list of cases in which applicationDidBecomeActive and applicationWillEnterForeground should be called ([ref](http://www.abdus.me/ios-programming-tips/applicationdidbecomeactive-vs-applicationwillenterforeground/))

applicationWillEnterForeground is called:

- when app is relaunched(comes from background to foreground)
- This method is not invoked when app starts for the first time i.e when applicationDidFinishLaunch is called but only when comes from background

applicationDidBecomeActive is called

- when app is first launched after didFinishLaunching.
- after applicationWillEnterForeground if there’s no URL to handle.
- after application:handleOpenURL: is called.
- after applicationWillResignActive if user ignores interruption like a phone call or SMS.
- after disappearing of alertView anywhere from the application